# Styles not cascading appropriately

Tags: css

I'm building a Wordpress theme, and I have these snippets in my style.css:

```
#content a:link, #content a:visited, #content a:hover, #content a:active {
  color: #fff;
}

.entry-utility a:link, .entry-utility a:visited, .entry-utility a:hover, .entry-utility a:active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
}
```

The problem is that all links, even those within a `<div class="entry-utility">` are being rendered with `color: #fff"`. The `background` selector in the second snippet works fine, but not the `color:` selector. I've checked, and that is definitely the most granular color selector. What could be causing this?

I've tried commenting out the first one, which does cause the second one to work. As far as I can tell, it's just using the least granular selector for all the links in my theme.

Comment: Have you used FireBug to figure out what style is being applied? If all else fails, you can use !important but that's obviously not a great solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put `color: #111;` in rule that is more precise than `#content a` like this.

```
#content div.entry-utility a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhh... because .entry-utility isn't more granular - you could use the class outside of the #content div. Didn't think of that. Thank you so much!